# Vectorizing nested if-statements

Tags: performance, matlab, vectorization

**Problem**
I am processing roughly 18 million point data sets at the moment that run through different processes. Over the profile viewer I found out that one of my bottlenecks is this part of code and hence I was wondering if it is possible to vectorize multiple if-statements.

**Code**

```
WA=zeros(size(NB_list_z,1),3);
for i=1:size(NB_list_z,1);
    if (NB_list_z(i,2)==0||NB_list_z(i,3)==0);        
    WA(i,1)=BMLS(NB_list_z(i,1),5);

    else
       if (BMLS(NB_list_z(i,3),5)>=COG);
       WA(i,1)=(BMLS(NB_list_z(i,3),5)+BMLS(NB_list_z(i,2),5)+BMLS(NB_list_z(i,1),5))/3;    
            if (WA(i,1)<COG);
                if (BMLS(NB_list_z(i,2),5)>=COG);
               WA(i)=(BMLS(NB_list_z(i,2),5)+BMLS(NB_list_z(i,1),5))/2;                           
                    if (WA(i,1)<COG);
                  WA(i,1)=BMLS(NB_list_z(i,1),5);                  
                    end 
                else
                WA(i,1)=BMLS(NB_list_z(i,1),5);                
                end 
            end 
        else
             if (BMLS(NB_list_z(i,2),5)>=COG);
               WA(i,1)=(BMLS(NB_list_z(i,2),5)+BMLS(NB_list_z(i,1),5))/2;

                  if (WA(i,1)<COG);
                  WA(i,1)=BMLS(NB_list_z(i,1),5);                 
                 end 
             else
                WA(i,1)=BMLS(NB_list_z(i,1),5);               
             end          
       end
    end  
end
```

**Code Description**

`NB_list_z` contains the indexes of the neighbors of the points in the first column (in z direction -every point can have up to two points above.)
`BMLS` contains the values for the threshold I want to check.
`COG` is the threshold value.
Consider the lowest block = Block1 , the one above = Block2 and the one over as Block3.

The first if-clause sets the value to the value of Block1 if there are no neighbors existing above.

After that I want to combine blocks in the most profitable way for me.
Meaning that if Blocks 3+2+1 are above the threshold I want to include them all, but the highest block (here block 3) always has to be over the threshold alone as well.
If not then 2+1 with the same conditions and if not then only 1.
The code above works perfectly fine on small data sets but starts to take a lot of time for bigger data sets.

**Question**

I am new to "code optimization" and "vectorization" in that sense that I only started with it. I found some entries about removing for-loops and the like but I couldn't find anything to remove or simply multiple if-clauses. Hence the question is it possible to vectorize nested if-clauses ?

Answer (score 2):

The code is a bit too long to rewrite on this forum and definitely too long too rewrite without testing in against test data with expected output. However, let me write a bit about "vectorization" instead.

**What is vectorization?**

So, when we talk about vectorization in MATLAB we commonly mean that we apply certain operations on a vector instead of each element in the vector. A bit oversimplyfied we can see it as if we, instead of applying an operation on each element in the vector, using function taking a vector as input instead. For this to be effective, the operation need to have MATLAB support. What I mean is that the heavy work should be performed by a compiled file (mex-file).

**How is is done?**

When you want to apply this to all elements in a vector, it is really simple. For example, instead of doing,

```
a = 1:2:20;
total = 0;
for k = a %(range-based)
    total = total + a;
end
%for ind = 1:length(a) %(same result)
%    total = total + a(ind);
%end
```

it is possible to do it like this instead,

```
a = 1:2:20;
total = sum(a);
```

In case there you have an if statement in the loop it is still possible to vectorize this. Assume you want to sum all elements smaller than 11 and larger than 11 separately,

```
a = 1:2:20
total1 = sum(a(a<11));
total2 = sum(a(a>11));
```

However, in case you have nested if statements it gets more complicated. You will likely need to split the operation in a number of expressions. Each branch of the if statement needs to be handled separately. Each nested if statement need will be seen as a subset of the outer if statement. Thus it can be handled using `and` (`&`).

```
b = rand(10);
c = zeros(10);
c(b<0.5) = 0;
c(b>=0.5 & b<0.8) = 2*(c(b>=0.5 & b<0.8).^2);
c(b>=0.8) = 1;
```

**When do I vectorize**

It may not be worth vectorizing if a function is used only a few times and execute "sufficiently fast". After this it becomes a trade-off between complexity and efficiency. A function executing in a 100th of a second may still need optimizing if it is called 10000 times during an execution. Normally the more general functions needs optimization since these seems to attract a higher number of function calls. Also in case you run nested for loops where there is a dependency between the loops, these functions tend to be hard to vectorize.

```
a = 2:2:20;
for (m=1:length(a))
    for (n=1:length(a))
        if (m~=n)
            a(n) = a(n)/2; 
        end
    end
    a(a>5) = 2*a(a>5);
end
```

This becomes quite complicated, where the inner loop depends on the specific iteration of the outer loop. It may still be possible to solve, but you will have a problem similar to finding an orthogonal parametrization to a double integral. In case it is not absolutely necessary it may not be worth the effort and even if it is crucial to vectorize this it may still be worth to redefine the problems in terms of a more vectorizable manner than vectorizing these loops.

**Some last words**

Note that for large data sets a vectorization may generate copies of a large number of elements. Make sure that you are not modifing the input to a function since Matlab uses copy-on-write.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you explain your "last words" a bit more detailed ? I am not quite sure what you mean with it! :)

Comment: And is there a way instead of vectorization to use logical operations to decrease the runtime ? or would that get to complicated as well ? 100 thanks!

Comment: @KiW There are different techinques of passing parameters to functions. Matlab uses a technique called "copy-on-write". In case you want to learn more about it you can find some articles on the web. What it means is basically that if you pass a variable to a function without modifying it, Matlab will only pass a reference to the variable. However, if you modify the variable Matlab will instead pass a copy to the function. This will make it impossible for a function to modify variables in the caller, but will also make matlab copy large amount of data.

Comment: so if I understand you correctly if i dont modify my input variable within the function matlab doesnt need to copy the variable and will hence run faster ?

Comment: @KiW to the second comment, this is not exactly relevant. Vectorization means that you pass an array to a function instead of writing a for loop in Matlab. You can use logical operations to deduce what part of the array to be passed to a function. Instead of `if(myvar(i)>3)` giving the result `true, false, true, true` and you enter the if statement in case 1,3,4 and modify index 1,3,4. You can instead do, `q = myvar(myvar>3); (which return `[true,false,true,true]`); res = alg(myvar(q)) `.And modifying variables in function may actually give memory overflow in case the variable is large enough.

Comment: hmm thanks again, i will think about the logical part didnt quit get that but it looks like something i could use!

Comment: My guess is that the real problem you have is to understand vectorization. You should find look for tutorials on this. There is no magic.It is about passing arrays to built in functions (written eg C, ... and compiled) which use more effective operations than loops ( egmultiplication of sparse matrices does not require O(n^3) operations). You must find a trend in your algorithm so that you can  so you can handle all elements in one go instead of doing it element by element. Do it to all elements where the `if(arg)` is true instead of loop through all element and do something if `arg` is true.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116171/discussion-between-kiw-and-patrik).

Comment: Ups I am not sure that I wanted to move that into chat ... I am still not aware of all functions here. But yes you are absolutely right, I am still trying to understand vectorization especially in combination with if-clauses. I am preparing another question which has some easier and shorter code. For me it always works best if I can see it on one of my own examples because then I understand it better.

Comment: @ Patrik   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38142352/vectorize-loop-with-nested-if-clause if would appreciate some more help :)