# Vectorize loop with nested if-clause

Tags: performance, matlab, vectorization

**Problem**

I am trying to optimize the runtime of my code and have asked a similar question before that included several nested if-statements.
[Vectorizing nested if-statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38125770/vectorizing-nested-if-statements/38141025?noredirect=1#comment63713271_38141025)

As the code I posted there hoping for some ideas I might implement was a bit long and I am still struggeling with the implementation of vectorization for nested loops I would like to ask again with some easier code:

**Code**

```
NB_list_all=zeros(length(BML),4);
for NB=1:length(BML);
    NB_list=zeros(4,1);
    %in +x direction
    if isempty(find(BML(:,2)==BML(NB,2)+x_blockdimension & BML(:,3)==BML(NB,3), 1));
        NB_list(1,1)=0;
    else
        NB_list(1,1)=find(BML(:,2)==(BML(NB,2)+x_blockdimension)& BML(:,3)==BML(NB,3));

    end
NB_list_z(NB,:)=NB_list;
end

% BML(:,2) stores the x-coordinate
% BML(:,3) stores the y-coordinate
```

**Some example data**

```
BML=
    1 1005  115
    2 1100  115
    3 1419  120
    4 1424  120
    5 660   115
    6 655   115
```

Notice BML has a size of 170 000 x 7.

**Code Description**

What I am trying with this code is finding the next point in my point cloud which is "x_blockdimension" away. If nothing can be found the entry is set to zero. Now as this takes a huge amount of time for 18 Million points (and I am not just looking in one direction) I am looking for a way to optimize this by either using vectorization or logical indexing. If there is another way to improve the runtime I would be happy for any tips.

**What I tried**

```
if isempty(find(BML(:,2)==BML(:,2)+x_blockdimension & BML(:,3)==BML(:,3), 1));
    NB_list(1,1)=0;
else
    NB_list(1,1)=find(BML(:,2)==(BML(:,2)+x_blockdimension)& BML(:,3)==BML(:,3));

end
```

But it is not really doing what I want it to do.

I hope for some help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the format of inputs correctly, you can use broadcasting with [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) for a vectorized solution like so -

```
% Perform broadcasted comparison corresponding to the iterative comparison
% in original code to get a boolean array/mask. 
% Get the row, col indices for the mask, which will correspond to the index
% values and positions where those values are to be stored in the output. 
[R,C] = find(bsxfun(@eq,BML(:,2),BML(:,2).'+x_blockdimension) & ...
                                     bsxfun(@eq,BML(:,3),BML(:,3).'));

% Setup output array and store the indices at respcetive positions. 
NB_list_z_out = zeros(size(BML,1),numel(NB_list));
NB_list_z_out(C,1) = R;
```

Please note that it seemed that the output is only editing the first column elements in the output array and therefore indexing with `NB_list_z_out(C,1)` at the last step.

---

An alternative approach could be suggested with focus on memory efficiency and additionally performance too and get `R` and `C`, which could be used later on just like they were used in the approach listed earlier. The implementation would look something like this -

```
% Filter out with "bsxfun(@eq,BML(:,3),BML(:,3).'))".
[~,~,idx] = unique(BML(:,3),'stable');
vidx = find(ismember(idx,find(accumarray(idx(:),1)>1)));

% Filter out on remaining ones with valid indices (vidx)
[R1,C1] = find(bsxfun(@eq,BML(vidx,2),BML(vidx,2).'+x_blockdimension));
R = vidx(R1);
C = vidx(C1);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ... I tried implementing it but I get following error: ´Error using bsxfun
Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.

Error in test_neighbours (line 3)
                                     bsxfun(@eq,BML(:,3),BML(:,3).'));´

Comment: @KiW What's the size of `BML` with your actual case?

Comment: @ Divakar roughly 170 000x7 and i would like to implement it for a simlar process with 500 000 x 7 and the first case I need to run 4 times (in +x -x +y -y direction)

Comment: @ Divakar: If it helps I know there only exists one (or none) value for every element in BML which fullfills the condition of +x_blockdimension and I need to find the index of that.

Comment: I tried to use your implementation, I edited the question with the problems of that. I am not sure I get 100 % what your code does so I am wondering if there is a way to use it in the way needed. But thanks a lot anyway

Comment: sorry I played around with it, I used that at first but the problem remains the same :/

Comment: @KiW Could you upload your input data on some public storage site by any chance? So that we could run it at our ends.

Comment: @ Any suggestions on a proper website?

Comment: @KiW Not sure, but if you google for "upload file", you could find few I think.

Comment: @ Divakar  http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=05161766586627414815 thats the "BML" file , x_blockdimension is just=5

Comment: sorry for the stupid website (with all the adds) but didnt really want to register anywhere for this

Comment: @KiW And what's the value for `x_blockdimension` for your tests? No worries, I was able to download the mat file.

Comment: @ Divakar see comment above - x_blockdimension =5

Comment: @ Divakar in another process I want to do the same with constant x and y values to find z-value plus z_blockdimension (BML is just a part of the dataset) , that one is even slower than this due to the two equal terms ... , so it would be awesome if you find a solution if you could explain it a bit so that i could adapt it. thanks a lot for all your help!

Comment: do you want me to upload the results from my process as well ?

Comment: @KiW Just edit to this : `[R1,C1] = find(bsxfun(@eq,BML(vidx,2),BML(vidx,2).'+x_blockdimension) & bsxfun(@eq,BML(vidx,3),BML(vidx,3).'));`.

Comment: if i wanted to add a third dimension ( so x,y,z) can i just add it in the same way to the line you just eddited or do I have to have two stable indexes then ? ... Those lines you wrote are quite hard to understand for me tbh :D

Comment: @KiW Depends on the way you would be using the conditional on `z`. But that `bsxfun` part would extend to include `BML(vidx,4)`.

Comment: I edited above just for a quick look, while delete it afterwards again. Basically its the same thing just having the plus dimension on z whereas x and y stay constant

Comment: @KiW Few changes : `[~,~,idx] = unique(BML(:,2:3),'rows','stable'); [R1,C1] = find(bsxfun(@eq,BML(vidx,4),BML(vidx,4).'+z_blockdimension) & bsxfun(@eq,BML(vidx,3),BML(vidx,3).') & bsxfun(@eq,BML(vidx,2),BML(vidx,2).'));` I think.

Comment: unfortunately I am getting the memory error again with 3 dimensions (as the size of the matrix is no 220000x7) ... vidx = [] so I guess the problem is in the first two rows ...

Comment: @KiW On memory issues with large datasets, you can calculate `vidx`, which basically mean valid indices to iterate through the rows. Thus, you could stick with your loopy code and use `vidx`. So, `for NB=1:length(BML)` could be replaced by `for NB=1:length(vidx)` and proceed with your loopy code, which would give you equivalents of `R1` and `C1`. At the end of everything, we need to index back with `vidx(R1)` and so on.

Comment: Hm I think the problem for three dimensions is that vidx (I used it with your few changes above) contains all indices and isnt reduced as in the two dimensional one. So as long as I dont figure out why I cant use it for the three dimensional loop either

Answer (score 1):

If you know that there is only 0 or 1 match for every row in BML, then you can sort them and use diff, rather than using a loop:

```
%%  Find matches for x dimension

% sort on x dimension using sortrows, then split the matrix again
BMLx= sortrows(BML(:,[2:end,1]));
sorted_xx = BMLx(:,1:end-1);
idx = BMLx(:,end);

diff_ = diff(sorted_xx);
x_diff_match = find(diff_(:,1)==x_blockdimension & (diff_(:,2:end)==0));
% or you might want to use abs(a-b)<told

% assign all zeros as default
NB_list_x=zeros(length(BML),1);
% alocate matches
NB_list_x(idx(x_diff_match)) = idx(x_diff_match+1)
```

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer. i know that there is only one value for x+x-dimension with the same y value, in total there are more that fullfill the condition. if i look at your code it doesnt seem in coorporated or am i just too slow to see it ?

Comment: sorry, misunderstood the problem. now checks other diff(other_dimesions==0)

Comment: I tried implementing your solution, it looks like a good idea, especially for big data sets but I just get zeros as neighbours. And to be honest I have no idea why ... if you have some time I uploaded the data set here: s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=05161766586627414815 ... might be easier to see the outcome then. And I guess you mean ´(diff_(:,2)==0)´ as otherwise the matrix dimensions dont agree. But I would be glad if you had any idea why the outcome is just zeros :/ Thanks for your help!

Comment: would be very happy if you had an solution because your way seems a lot a faster, I just cant figure out the problem ...

Comment: Hi KiW, I just had a quick look at your tinyupload file. The issue might be that the first column of the tinyupload file contains large integers, whereas  the example in your post had 1:end. If these are some other index numebrs, would it work you replace them with 1:length(BML)? otherwise if the first colum is actually x-values, cat on a 1:n vector before the first column.